# Would like to know whether a directory exist or not inside my Xcode project using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created a directory inside my project using this code

```
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);    
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/createDirectory1"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) 
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
    NSLog(@"Create a new Dir");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Dir already exist");
}
```

now I want to check whether the directory exist or not? how can I get that through objective c code ?

Comment: You're already doing it: `if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])`

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7541965/3976183

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a directory exists in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541943/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/createDirectory1", docPath];
    BOOL fileExists=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    if (!fileExists)
    {

    }
    else
    {
       // Your Code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly,you should get the project path .you can do it like the codes bellow

```
NSString *getProjectPath(){
    NSString *projectPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s,__FILE__]; // your project path may have some same  prefix  to the macro __FILE__. 
    // do something 
    return projectPath;
}
```

then you use 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath] check if it exist

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL fileOrDirectoryExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath];
```

`fileExistsAtPath:dataPath` method returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a file or directory exists at a specified path. you are already doing it, as remus said.